# Are companies in the United Kingdom entitled to make data subject access requests?

Tags: united-kingdom, data-protection

Are companies in the United Kingdom entitled to make data subject access requests, or is this right limited to non-companies such as individuals?

Which statute permits or prevents them from doing so?

Answer (score 2):

No. The Data Protection Act 1998 provides a 'Right of access to personal data' to "an individual". See [Section 7, subsection 1](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/29/section/7#section-7-1).

Although the word 'person' can mean a company in a legal context, the word 'individual' does not.

Comment: Could you provide an exact citation in the act (section? paragraph?) and perhaps quote the sentence in context? This will ensure the claim can be checked and that the cited statute supports it.

Comment: @Nij Done in an edit.

Comment: The sentence contains a list of four items with five sub-items, so I'm not going to quote it.